# Is it possible to spoof the data that web beacons/tracking pixels collect? If so, how can one prevent it?

Tags: javascript, beacon, tracking-pixel

I have a use-case where I am trying to collect crucial data with a web beacon/tracking pixel. I'm trying to create something similar to what SpotX does to verify how much of a video ad the user watched. They do it by placing a beacon at certain times of the video with a view_percent field indicating the % of how much the user watched. For example, in a 1 minute video they would place a beacon at 12 seconds with view_percent set to 20 which then lets their server know that the user has watched 20% of the video.

But the user could just modify the beacon and change the view_percent to 100, how could I prevent that or verify that the data hasn't been tamperedwith?

Comment: ultimately, you can't guarantee it, IMO. It's coming from the client, any data coming from client could be tempered with / forged somehow. You can make things difficult, for instance using some digital signature is coming to mind, or ensure that a hardly predictable token is passed along. That would make most of the users unable / unwanting to make the effort. Following your example, they may be checking that all other beacons have sent their report. And/or they may use a token that is received only after the last beacon has reported.

Comment: I would also add this question looks more fitted for [security.se]